# Taiko Automated Tests - get DOM element

Tags: javascript, getgauge

What is the best way to get a DOM element in a Taiko test?

In the browser console I can do:

`element = document.getElementsByClassName("XXXX")[0]`

I've tried `element = await $('.XXXX').get()[0];` using Taiko's `$` selector (https://taiko-preview.gauge.org/#$). But that doesn't seem to give the actual DOM element (just a Taiko `ElementWrapper` (https://taiko-preview.gauge.org/#elementwrapper)).

For context, the reason I want the DOM element is because I'd like to do `element.parentElement` and then look at some of the properties to use in my test.

I'm relatively new to Taiko so any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [evaluate method](https://taiko.gauge.org/#evaluate) in Taiko here. For example, to get the classname from the parent element you could do

```
evaluate(()=>{var a = document.getElementsByClassName('XXXX')[0]; return a.parentElement.className})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [evaluate](https://taiko.gauge.org/#evaluate) method to get DOM element. You can return the attribute values from this method or set the value of them. Here is the example,

```
 // For getting an attribute value
 const color = await evaluate(textBox({ class: 'username' }), (element) => {
    return element.style.color;
 });

 // For setting/getting an attribute
 const updatedMaxLength = await evaluate(textBox({ class: 'username' }), (element) => {
    element.setAttribute('maxlength', 20);
    return element.getAttribute('maxlength');
 });
```

In your case it should be,

```
 const inputMaxLength = await evaluate(textBox({ class: 'username' }), (element) => {
    return element.parentElement.className
 });
```

You can also use **XPath** of the element to use with evaluate method,

```
const passwordXpath = `//input[@type="password"]`;
const passwordMaxLength = await evaluate($(passwordXpath), (element) => {
    return element.getAttribute('maxlength');
});
```